# Sharing Data between Two Threads with Queues in Python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have two threads.

```
def collectorFunction():
    # collectInformation
    # add to List
    list.append(myReceivedData)

def senderFunction):
    time.sleep(60)
    sendList.append(list[:])
    del list[:]
    # send information

t1 = Thread(target = collectorFunction)
t1.daemon = True
t1.start()
t2 = Thread(target = senderFunction)
t2.daemon = True
t2.start()
```

What Im trying to do is to run a thread in the background constantly collecting information over UDP Broadcast. I take that information, queue it up, and send it to another location. Basically a monitoring device. I figured it would be less network intensive queueing up the information to send a chunk of data over a JSON call.

At the moment Im using a global variable. But Im loathe to use that. I've just read up on queues. Most of the examples I've seen would show the collectorFunction in this example, putting to the queue, and the senderFunction getting from the queue.

But what I need is for the collectorFunction to indefinitely put into the queue, with the senderFunction to get everything it can from the queue, process, then wait for sixty seconds before trying again.

An example I've seen shows:

```
def func2(num, q):
    while num < 100000000:
        num = q.get()
        print num,
```

Not quite sure how to re-write this for my needs?

Perhaps

```
def senderFunction(queue):
    while 1:
        while len(queue) > 0:
            item = queue.get()
            # do what I need with the items
        time.sleep(60)
```

Does this make sense? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: [`queue.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get) blocks. You do not need to sleep.

Comment: Hmm. OK. But I don't want to necessarily process as soon as there's information. I only want to process every minute - hence the time.sleep()

Comment: In our days if we got it to work was the best thing. Now you ask if it is good or not. Hahaha. It is wonderful if it is working!